# Sharepoint SearchBox Alt Text

Tags: sharepoint, search, alt

How can I replace default alt text of sharepoint search box that displays when hovering on it as shown in this picture:

[image: Sharepoint Search Box]

Which property of this webpart should I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find details about search box customization in [this post](http://littletalk.wordpress.com/2009/12/03/hide-advanced-search-link-from-smallsearchinputbox/).

You can change the alt text with jQuery (SP 2010):

```
$("#s4-searcharea input).attr('title') = "<SOME NEW TEXT>";
```